# Updating a pandas column for a given date range no longer works after creating a new column

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe, indexing

I have a pandas dataframe with a date index. I can update one of its columns for a given date range all fine but it does not work if a new column based on that is created first:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://pylie.com/dl/readings/bikes-nyc-pylie.csv', index_col=0)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

print(df.tail(5))

df.loc['2016-10-29':]['temperature'] = 20.0
print(df.tail(5))

df['temperature_f'] = df['temperature'].copy()

df.loc['2016-10-29':]['temperature'] = 40.0
print(df.tail(5))
```

output:

```
            temperature  precipitation  brooklyn  manhattan  williamsburg  queensboro
date                                                                                 
2016-10-27          8.6          35.81       651       1558          2137        1902
2016-10-28          7.5           0.00      2021       3872          4271        3202
2016-10-29         10.6           0.00      1639       3160          4027        2920
2016-10-30         19.1          14.22      1702       2971          3531        2547
2016-10-31          9.4           0.00      2648       4876          5440        3720

            temperature  precipitation  brooklyn  manhattan  williamsburg  queensboro
date                                                                                 
2016-10-27          8.6          35.81       651       1558          2137        1902
2016-10-28          7.5           0.00      2021       3872          4271        3202
2016-10-29         20.0           0.00      1639       3160          4027        2920
2016-10-30         20.0          14.22      1702       2971          3531        2547
2016-10-31         20.0           0.00      2648       4876          5440        3720

            temperature  precipitation  brooklyn  manhattan  williamsburg  queensboro  temperature_f
date                                                                                                
2016-10-27          8.6          35.81       651       1558          2137        1902            8.6
2016-10-28          7.5           0.00      2021       3872          4271        3202            7.5
2016-10-29         20.0           0.00      1639       3160          4027        2920           20.0
2016-10-30         20.0          14.22      1702       2971          3531        2547           20.0
2016-10-31         20.0           0.00      2648       4876          5440        3720           20.0
```

pandas version is 0.24.1

Comment: Do not chain index `df.loc['2016-10-29':]['temperature'] = 40.0`, instead, do `df.loc['2016-10-29':,'temperature'] = 40.0`. It should work as expected.

Comment: See *Why does assignment fail when using chained indexing* part in [this doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html).

Comment: Yours worked and the doc shared also helped. Thanks @QuangHoang!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
df.loc['2016-10-29':, 'temperature'] = 20.0
```

Add the selector for the index and the column you are trying to update in the same .loc call, otherwise there is no guarantee that the original DataFrame will be updated. This is also applicable to updating an existing column.

When adding a new column you don't need to use `.copy()`. So, `df['temperature_f'] = df['temperature']` is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks! This one works fine. I did not know about this method.